# Stochastic Integrals: Approximating $f(t,\omega)$ by $ke^{-kt} \int_0^t e^{ks} f(s,\omega)ds$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $f_N(s,\omega)$ be some bounded jointly measurable function in the product space $L^1([0,T],\mathscr{L},\mu_L) \times (\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$.

For such an $f_N$ we define a function $g_k$ for $k>0$ by 
$$g_k(t,\omega) = ke^{-kt} \int_0^t e^{ks} f_N(s,\omega)ds.$$ 
In this case, for any $\epsilon>0$, how do we find an $g_k$ for which

$\int_0^T E | f_N(t,\cdot) - g_k(t,\cdot)|^2 dt < \epsilon$?

This is part of a proof from Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations. I would greatly appreciate any help.

> Now a function $f \in \mathcal{L}_{T}^{2}$ is generally not mean-square continuous, but we can approximate it arbitrarily closely in the norm (2.5) by one that is. To begin, we approximate $f$ by a bounded function $f_{N} \in \mathcal{L}_{T}^{2}$ defined by
>   $$
> f_{N}(t, \omega)=\max \{-N, \min \{f(t, \omega), N\}\}
> $$
>   for some $N>0 .$ Obviously $\left|f_{N}(t, \omega)\right| \leq N,$ with $f_{N}(t, \omega)=f(t, \omega)$ for those $(t, \omega)$ for which $|f(t, \omega)| \leq N .$ Moreover
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{T} E\left(\left|f_{N}(t, \cdot)-f(t, \cdot)\right|^{2}\right) d t \leq 4 \int_{0}^{T} E\left(|f(t, \cdot)|^{2}\right) d t<\infty
> $$
>   so by the Dominated Convergence Theorem 2.2 .3 applied to the functions $E\left(\left|f_{N}(t, \cdot)-f(t, \cdot)\right|^{2}\right)$ in $L^{1}\left([0, T], \mathcal{L}, \mu_{L}\right)$ it follows that
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{T} E\left(\left|f_{N}(t, \cdot)-f(t, \cdot)\right|^{2}\right) d t \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { as } \quad N \rightarrow \infty
> $$
>   Then for such an $f_{N}$ we define a function $g_{k}$ for $k>0$ by
>   $$
> g_{k}(t, \omega)=k e^{-k t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{k s} f_{N}(s, \omega) d s
> $$
>   From the properties of $f_{N}$ and the fact that the above integrand does not involve values of $f_{N}$ for times exceeding $t,$ it follows that $g_{k}$ is jointly $\mathcal{L} \times \mathcal{A}$ measurable and that $g_{k}(t, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal{A}_{t}$ -measurable for each $t \in[0, T] .$ Also from the bound on $\left|f_{N}\right|$ we have
>   $$
> \left|g_{k}(t, \omega)\right| \leq N\left(1-e^{-k t}\right)
> $$
>   so $E\left(g_{k}(t, \cdot)^{2}\right)$ is finite and integrable over $0 \leq t \leq T ;$ hence $g_{k} \in \mathcal{L}_{T}^{2} .$ Finally, the sample paths of $g_{k}$ satisfy
>   $$
> \left|g_{k}(t, \omega)-g_{k}(s, \omega)\right| \leq 2 k N|t-s|
> $$
>   and are thus continuous. In fact this bound also implies that $E\left(g_{k}(t, \cdot)^{2}\right)$ is continuous, that is $g_{k}$ is mean-square continuous. Consequently we can approximate it by a step function $f^{(n)} \in \mathcal{S}_{T}^{2}$ as in the first part of the proof. For any given $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $f_{N}, g_{k}$ and $f^{(n)}$ successively so that
>   $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> \left\|f-f_{N}\right\|_{2, T}<\frac{1}{3} \epsilon, \quad\left\|f_{N}-g_{k}\right\|_{2, T}<\frac{1}{3} \epsilon \\
> \left\|g_{k}-f^{(n)}\right\|_{2, T}<\frac{1}{3} \epsilon
> \end{array}
> $$
>   Then by the triangle inequality $(1.4 .37)$ we have
>   $$
> \left\|f-f^{(n)}\right\|_{2, T}<\epsilon
> $$
>   which is what we were required to prove. $\square$

[(Transcribed from this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAtDE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can write $g_k$ as the convolution $g_k = f_N * \psi_k$, where $\psi_k(t) = k e^{-kt}\mathbf{1}_{t>0}$ is delta-like. Since $f_N(\cdot,\omega)\in L^2(0,T)$ for almost all $\omega$, then
$$
||g_k(\cdot,\omega) - f_N(\cdot,\omega)||_{L^2[0,T]} \to 0,k\to\infty,
$$
for such $\omega$. Thanks to boundedness, $||g_k - f_N||^2_{2,T}\to 0$, $k\to\infty$ (I guess that $||f||^2_{2,T}$ is just the expectation of $||f||^2_{L^2[0,T]}$).